# Ubuntu Not Starting After Installing Software Updates

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, troubleshooting, grub, updates, wubi

I just did a software update on my Ubuntu 9.10.  After that it asked me to restart my system.  Once I did that, grub opened a command prompt.  How do I run ubuntu now?

Ubuntu 9.10 was installed 1 week ago using the Wubi installer.  It is installed on the same partition as WinXP.  I gave it 12 GB of space while installing Ubuntu.  It was working good for a week.  I decided to do the software updates this morning and now it's not even starting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution [here](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8473964&postcount=13), but I would do a regular Ubuntu install from a CD. Wubi is slower and less stable.